# Magento update error via magento connect to 1.9.1

Tags: magento

I tried to update `Magento` via `Magento Connect` to 1.9.1, but I got an error. The site is down and shows this error.
[image: Magento Installation Wizard Error]

plz help

```
Warning: include_once(Mage.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/altphp/lib/php') in /home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49

Warning: include_once(Mage.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/lib:/usr/local/altphp/lib/php') in /home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php:49) in /home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php on line 56

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php:49) in /home/newspape/public_html/fcdpl/downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php on line 56

Checking dependencies of packages
Already installed: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.1.1, skipping
```

Comment: converted link to embedded image

Answer (score 0):

Try after giving full permission to your Magento folder. It may work after that.